# Is there a way to automatically wrap widgets within a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Sorry if this is a dup, I see a lot of questions regarding text wrapping, but not generic widget wrapping in a row.

I have a dynamic row of buttons within a row. I'd like to wrap the buttons to create a second row if the list becomes longer than the width of the screen. Is it possible to do this automatically, or do I need to manually detect and create the correct number of rows.

If the latter, does anybody have pointers to measuring a widget's width vs screen width? Right now I'm doing something like:

```
...
return Row(
  children: List.generate(count*2 + 1, (i) {
    if (i %2 == 0) {
      return Spacer();
    }
    return RaisedButton(child: Text((i / 2).round().toString(), onPressed: (){...});
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row is useful when you need to organize child widgets in a single line. [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) with default direction is an alternative to Row that moves child widgets to the next line if there is no enough space